# How to use multiple redundant exporter in Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, exporter

We are using the [Kafka Exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) to monitor our cluster with up to 10 brokers in some regions.

At the moment, only the first broker of each cluster has an exporter running, because a single exporter can expose the state of a whole cluster. But we want to use the exporter on all nodes to get metrics even if one node is down.

As every kafka exporter is exporting the cluster state (instead of the state of the node), we don't not how to configure Prometheus properly.

For e.g.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: kafka
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - host1:9308
        - host2:9308
        - ...
```

Would fetch the metrics from all hosts, but we would need some kind of fallback configuration. Host2 would deliever the same metrics as Host1.

How can we do that?

Comment: Not every metric is the same. For example, topic count and byte ingestion rate are different for each broker.

Comment: What makes you thinks so? My colleague and I checked them and actually it looks like we get the whole ingestion rate on just one node. We are observing consumergroup_current_offset as well as topic_partition_current_offset

Comment: You get that *per node*, yes. I don't see how an exporter attached to one node would be able to get metrics from all others, but it seems like that project uses Kafka admin api

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the JMX metrics, which the README of that project says should be used instead to get different metrics

Comment: Well Kafka uses Zookeeper to synchronize between the brokers - as far as I know. Also if you publish data into a Kafka cluster you would not connect to each broker for sending data. Usually its enough to connect to one broker. So every broker should be aware of the cluster state and also delegate read/write actions to different brokers, right?

Comment: It sounds like you just need a reverse proxy/load balancer, then you would point Prometheus at that, though

Comment: Your exporter doesn't give you heap usage and GC rates, for example. Those are only available per server. Same for byte rates per topic-partition on specific replicas of topics

Comment: Well I did not ask for it, did I? ;)
We count processed documents an as the offset is part of the "cluster state" it works well for us. So in short terms: There is not prometheus config to do this? I need to setup nginx for e.g.?

Comment: AFAIK, Prometheus doesn't know if multiple targets are the same or not, and just scrapes everything you tell it to. So, you'd have to consolidate metrics to one "target" endpoint